# URL with dashes and underscores altered when inserted into [name](url) notation

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, markdown

So, this is the URL:

```
http://code.google.com/p/es-lab/wiki/Talks#Changes_to_ECMAScript,_Part_2:_Harmony_Highlights_-_proxies_and
```

When I insert the URL like so:

```
[Title](URL)
```

the last part of the URL changes from

```
Highlights_-_proxies_and
```

to

```
Highlights/i-_proxies_and
```

What's going on here?

**Note:** See my comment below for a live demonstration of the issue! Feel free to copy the URL and try it for yourself... (It seems that the URL is only altered if the `[]()` notation appears within a comment, but not when it appears within a question/answer.)

Comment: [Proof](http://code.google.com/p/es-lab/wiki/Talks#Changes_to_ECMAScript,_Part_2:_Harmony_Highlights_-_proxies_and)

Comment: Confirmed. Also, it changes `ECMAScript,_Part_2` to `ECMAScript,iPart_2`.

Comment: Markdown parser bug - one underscore after the comma and one before the dash are turned into `<i>` tags, which are then sanitized. (educated guess)

Comment: It'd be saner to use a [URL shortener](http://j.mp).

Comment: +1, [this is still happening](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/939/markdown-linkurl-syntax-mangles-colons-in-urls/952#952), although [apparently](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19592/freehand-red-circles#comment40212_20033) now the angle brackets are no longer getting stripped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were actually two changes:

```
...#Changes_to_ECMAScript,iPart_2:_Harmony_Highlights/i-_proxies_and
                          ^                          ^^
```

The Markdown Mini parser applies its italics check before performing link conversion, and the comma is one of the characters that's allowed before an underscore (or asterisk) when looking for the italics pattern. This caused the "Part_2:_Harmony_Highlights/" part of your URL to be surrounded by an `<i>` tag pair, and the relevant underscores to be removed.

Since in the case of comments URL santitation is done by removing characters not on the whitelist, the angled brackets caused by the previous step were dropped and you were left you with just the `i`s.

The immediate solution to this is to simply escape the problematic first underscore, which will prevent the accidental italicising:

```
...#Changes_to_ECMAScript,\_Part_2:_Harmony_Highlights_-_proxies_and
                          ^
```

Comment: I see. I won't be using commas or dashes in my URL fragments then... (at least in scenarios where I have underscores as word-delimiters)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Whoops, I wasn't thinking fully yesterday though, there's a much saner way to work around this, per my edit.

Comment: Example comment: [escaped url](http://code.google.com/p/es-lab/wiki/Talks#Changes_to_ECMAScript,\_Part_2:_Harmony_Highlights_-_proxies_and)

Comment: OK, cool `:)` What's up with the `/` after `Highlights` though?

Comment: Ah, mistakenly copied it from the broken URL, where it was part of the closing `</i>`.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in your comment, this is fixed now. [Tim's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122604/115866) was absolutely correct; I finally fixed this when [enabling intra-word emphasis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240354/markdown-change-intra-word-emphasis-now-works) in comments, because that would have made this problem even worse.