# Links with underscores in comments are mangled

Tags: bug, comments, hyperlinks, underscore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [URL with dashes and underscores altered when inserted into [name](url) notation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122601/url-with-dashes-and-underscores-altered-when-inserted-into-nameurl-notation)

I tried to post a link in a comment and it gets mangled badly.

This is the link:

```
http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/25/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-1_2900_.aspx
```

I tried using the `[]()` syntax first, then raw, both got mangled when users tried clicking.

With the `[]()` syntax, the first and last underscores become `<i></i>`, with the raw URL, an ellipses is used in the middle of the text *and* the link, breaking it.

Posting both examples as comments here.

Comment: [Using link syntax](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/25/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-1_2900_.aspx)

Comment: Raw: http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/25/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-1_2900_.aspx

Comment: Note that the link has **4** underscores - may be related to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68555/bug-in-editor-when-rendering-links-with-four-underscores