# MarkDown syntax is interpreted inside comments hyperlink tooltip, but HTML tags are not

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, comments, markdown

Here's a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25069132/how-to-perform-string-manipulations-on-a-column-with-a-temporary-procedure#comment39122722_25129937).
And it's code :

```
Wouldn't be it better if the procedure were used on[`CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypes.MarkdownMini`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/242800 "from the links : the list of existing close reasons *(in markdown syntax)*")at the beginning?
```

I used Markdow syntax in the link tooltip[`CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypes.MarkdownMini`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/242800).

When you put your mouse over the link you see`*`appearing as`*(in markdown syntax)*`, but when used in a comment the markdown syntax is convert to HTML and HTML tags are not allowed, so it print`<i>(in markdown syntax)</i>`when putting the mouse over it.

We should either allow [the allowed set of html tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/242800), or use the post behaviour which don't convert the markdown syntax.

Comment: Comment markdown syntax is not the full syntax, it is "markdown mini", a subset.

Comment: @Oded : It don't explain why it is converted to HTML tags to be not interpreted later.

Comment: That's how the title attribute works in the browser. It doesn't support arbitrary HTML. Arguably, we shouldn't allow markdown at all in the bit that goes into the title.

Comment: @Oded : Yes but why don't doing the post behaviour? If you put your mouse over `CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypes.MarkdownMini`in my question, Markdown isn't converted to html tags.

Comment: @Martijn - if I understand the OP correctly, they mean that the title attribute shouldn't be converted to HTML at all, but kept as markdown (as it does for the link in the post itself - hover over the link to see) - it has the "help text" that comes up as a tooltip there, but in comments it does get converted to HTML. A discrepancy.

Comment: @Oded: ad, I missed that comments **do** interpret markdown in the link title. That's really a bug then.

Comment: @Oded : Write this code in a comment and a question/answer :`[CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypes.MarkdownMini](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-links "list *(in markdown syntax)*")`. Then put you mouse over the link to [get the link title](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown#Liens). You'll see that markdown is interpreted inside links titles. There is 2 way to fix it : 1- Allow [the allowed set of HTML tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/242800). 2- Use the post behaviour.

Comment: So, what is this? A feature request or a bug?

Comment: @ChrisF : It is a bug report: look at the question edit history. Implementing the feature request would be way to fix it.

Comment: Our [main markdown guru](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha) is on extended vacation right now and I'm not going to touch this for any amount of bounty (also, bounty refunded - try again in a week).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240815/115866), this now works as you expected.