# Is it useful to set a bounty to get a bug corrected?

Tags: discussion, bounties, bug-reports

Some moderators in the comments recognized my question described a real bug, but nothing happened after that.

Will it be useful to set a bounty on my meta.stackexchange question to get the bug fixed, or will that not change anything?

Comment: Not all moderators are SE employees.

Comment: @bjb568 : Of course, I wanted to talk about those who are member of the staff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting a bounty brings attention to your question.

On Meta.SE, they can be used to promote a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), but they can also be used for promoting the resolution of a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Chances are that an SE dev has already seen your report and, if it is relevant enough, is already working on a fix. However, a bounty can be used to speed up the process or give it more exposure if it hasn't yet been seen.

You could also resolve the bug yourself with a userscript or suggest that it be included in the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch (SOUP)](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch).

Comment: Userscripts can't be used in [my case](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237567/markdown-syntax-is-interpreted-inside-comments-hyperlink-tooltip-but-html-tags#comment778745_237567). It is not client side.

Comment: @user2284570 Then a bounty's your only option.

Comment: I don't know the time it take *(generally)* to get a bug fixed. Mine was posted only one day ago.

Comment: @user2284570 It depends, but a bounty might be enough to get an employee response.

Comment: Do you mean an another response? Oded already looked at the bug.

Comment: @user2284570 I see. It seems like [tag:status-bydesign] to me, which means that they're not planning on fixing it, but someone should have tagged it as such. I meant an "official response," either in the form of an answer or an edit to your post confirming the status.

Comment: No, otherwise you would looked [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/237567/revisions).

Comment: @user2284570 In that case, it's a [tag:bug] report phrased as a [tag:feature-request], in which case a bounty would be highly recommended.