# Is OK to write a comment on my question for asking to someone which may have an answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, unanswered-questions, technology

I put a tag on my question and nobody seems to give an appropriate answer even [with a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25838472/2284570), and if I [find a user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9021/nickf) with a very high reputation level and he describe himself as a nerd about that particular tag :

Then would be OK if post a comment like this on my question?

```
@user Any ideas?
```

**Edit:** I'm doing this in the case I consider the target user didn't read the question and that he may be able to write a better answer.

Comment: No. It would not.

Comment: Since this is an honest question and not a feature request, downvoting it is a rather ineffective way of saying "the answer is no"; one should rather upvote an answer that says "no".

Comment: Yep. Remember : the idea is bad. But the question is not about doing it. It is about if it is OK do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you shouldn't post this comment - I doubt if someone having definite ideas wouldn't write them.  Anyway, if you ask a question, anyone understands that you need some ideas - if you don't need them, don't ask :D

Bounty doesn't guarantee an answer you need, it is needed to promote your question, if you still need  an answer to your question, start another bounty.

**[To the edit]**

And remember that not any user must read your question. If you want some user who didn't comment or write answers to your question to help you with your problem, you can't ask him using comment replies (`@user`), invite him to the chat room and ask for the help.

Comment: `posting "any ideas" under his answer will cause "huh?"` but I'm talking about a user who didn't participate in my question. I also said I would post that kind of comment on my question... not on someone's answer of course.

Comment: @user2284570 so what do you mean by "he may be able to write a better answer"?

Comment: write a better answer than the currant's answers on my questions of course! I added this [temporary example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838472/how-to-get-video-height-and-width-from-a-mp4-url-with-client-side-only/25955498#comment40851628_25838472), please don't consider it, I'll delete it soon.

Comment: I did this because he described himself as a JavaScript nerd. I don't want make all user read my question *(This is the purpose of the bounty)*.

Comment: @user2284570 see full edit :)

Answer (score 7):

Be aware that @replies only notify users who have interacted with the associated post in some way (see the [comment @reply faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/214632) for details). So not only would the `@user Any ideas?` comment to your question be considered 100% noise and worthy of deletion on that basis alone, it would almost certainly be completely ineffective in gaining the attention of the user.

And **please** do not search out posts by that user and post comments on them to ask this user to look at your question.

Comment: What about [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237567/markdown-syntax-is-interpreted-inside-comments-hyperlink-tooltip-but-html-tags#comment778740_237567) then?

Comment: @user2284570: IMHO, Oded's comment is very likely a reply to a comment left (but later deleted) by Martijn. Not being a moderator here on MSE I cannot tell for certain, but orphaned replies certainly exist on math.SE (where I am a moderator and can see deleted comments).

Comment: At any rate, let's try it out: @Oded, did you get this ping? If so, what can you tell us about the comment linked by the OP in the comment above?

Comment: No, I was here to follow comments. Maybe he can because he is a moderator. Isn't it?